# Parsing data from Polars LazyFrame

Tags: python-polars

Pre-requisites: I'm collecting large amounts of data in CSV files with two columns. For storage and speed I'm trying to convert them to Parquet.

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Read a parquet file in a LazyFrame.
- Iterate through every cell of a column
- Extract the data from there, feed it to a function.
- Save the output of the function in a list (the output is a dict)
- Write the dicts to a new CSV file (I would also prefer to do this in a streaming way, because I can't hold in memory all the results)

```
df = pl.scan_parquet('big_file.pq')  
results = []
htmls = df.select(["html"]).collect(streaming=True)
counter = 0
for item in htmls:
    counter += 1
    if counter == 3:
        break
    result = parser(item)
    results.append(result)
```

With this code I end up with a series in my htmls variable, and I don't know how to iterate through it, searched the docs but unfortunately couldn't find a solution.

[Demo csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zm524WbAZeNqRH0W7v41XYEqjTKjWtgR/view?usp=share_link) ( the csv that I'm converting to Parquet before going into parsing)

Comment: Hi @NeonOni, possible to add a minimal reproducible example? that is - Polars code to create a minimal dataset (pl.DataFrame(..)) and a table example of what you wish to obtain?

Comment: Hi @Luca
The dataset  is built from some scraping activities. It has on one column the url of the page, on the other column it has the base64 encoding of the raw html (don't know how could I reproduce that here).
What I want is to iterate over those base64 encodings, basically to parse them offline, the result of the parsing is a dict, and all the dicts resulting from this parsing should be stored in a single new csv file.

Comment: what about with df.head(10).to_dicts() ? that will export a few rows of your dataframe to dicts. So it makes it easier to paste in the question

Comment: Can we assume that your `parser` function is not possible to rewrite in terms of polars expressions?

Comment: @Luca I can make a paste bin with 10 lines from the pq file, if it helps. Updated the post.

Comment: @TomNorway Exactly, it's just an base64 decoder + Selectolax

Comment: @Luca Do you think maybe it would be a good idea to get a polars doc page created that we could link to showing different "minimal polars code examples" e.g. with `.to_dicts()` as you suggested and perhaps other options like `pl.read_csv(io.StringIO(...))` etc.

Comment: @jqurious: absolutely, it's a good idea and I think it can make a difference with the Polars questions. You are thinking about a page on Polars user guide, or somewhere else?

If people are on board with this, I would be happy to propose something for it, unless you wish to do it?

Comment: @Luca I'm not sure the best place for it - maybe somewhere in the guide. If you're happing proposing it - please feel free to go ahead with it, thank you.

Comment: @NeonOni: I noticed that the file is over 500mb. Is it possible to share just a few lines of the file in the question? I understand that this is not a performance question, so a minimal reproducible example with about 5 lines would be the best place to start and help you

Comment: @Luca: Exactly 5 lines:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g_1onIX0fFDQuaXUbNYR3VRbZPuANjT1/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @NeonOni You say you want to convert CSV to Parquet, but then in the code you're trying to read Parquet and save it as CSV? Also, if you're feeding each row to a function - it's not entirely clear why you need `polars` at all here?

Comment: As I said above, this is a snippet from the csv file that I converted to parquet for this script.
I have 2 columns : url and html.
I need to parse each cell from html column but in batches or lazy, because the entire csv has 650gb. This is why I need polars. Because I can't process 650gb csv files with 128gb of ram.
so, after feeding my function with each cell from the html column, I get dicts back, I store the dicts in a list, then write the list of dicts to a new csv. this is the entire workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly your need, you can use the `apply` function for this.

Example:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.scan_csv('test_5_lines.csv')

def html_udf(html_string):
    return {
        'a': html_string[:5],
        'b': html_string[5:10],
        'c': html_string[4:12]
    }

(
    df.select(
        pl.col('html').apply(html_udf))
    .collect(streaming=True)
    .unnest('html')
    .write_csv('test_5_lines_result.csv')
)

# Here is the content of the resulting CSV file
a,b,c
CgoKC,goKIC,CgoKICA8
CgoKC,goKIC,CgoKICA8
CgoKC,goKIC,CgoKICA8
CgoKC,goKIC,CgoKICA8
```

UPDATE: example with UDF returning a dict.
I included the `unnest` after the `collect, as I believe the streaming does not support unnest yet.

@jqurious: if you see a better way of doing this, feel free to share.

You can also run your UDF in multi-threading with `strategy='threading'`, however you should be aware of what the Polars API on the multi-threading:

https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.apply.html#polars.Expr.apply

*strategy: {‘thread_local’, ‘threading’}
This functionality is in alpha stage. This may be removed /changed without it being considdered a breaking change.
‘thread_local’: run the python function on a single thread.
‘threading’: run the python function on separate threads. Use with
care as this can slow performance. This might only speed up your code if the amount of work per element is significant and the python function releases the GIL (e.g. via calling a c function)*

Comment: There is one slight issue with this approach. It will return the html header and every cell processed under it.
Imagine that html_udf method returns a dict, which always has the same keys.
The new csv that I write needs to have those new keys and of course with the corresponding values.

Comment: Hi @NeonOni, I just updated the answer with the UDF returning a dict. Let me know if this is what you are looking to obtain